RLS on superset



sales level 1
sales level 2
sales level 3




sl1
slm1
slmn1


sl1
slm1
slmn2


sl1
slm2
slmn3


sl1
slm2
slmn4


sl2
slm3
slmn5


sl2
slm3
slmn6


sl2
slm3
slmn7


sl2
slm3
slmn8


sl2
slm3
slmn9


sl2
slm3
slmn10


sl2
slm4
slmn11


sl2
slm4
slmn12



I've a hierarchy somewhat similar to this. I want to apply rls based on the same in superset in a way that sales level 1 can see data related to his subordinates sales level2 can see data related to saleslvel3. How can I achieve this?
SELECT sd.*
FROM sales_data sd
JOIN hierarchy h ON sd.sales_level_2 = h.sales_level_2 AND sd.sales_level_3 = h.sales_level_3
WHERE
    h.sales_level_1 = CURRENT_USER  -- Use Superset's CURRENT_USER placeholder
    OR
    (h.sales_level_1 = (SELECT sales_level_1 FROM hierarchy WHERE sales_level_2 = h.sales_level_2 AND sales_level_3 = h.sales_level_3 AND sales_level_1 = CURRENT_USER))
    OR
    (h.sales_level_1 = (SELECT sales_level_1 FROM hierarchy WHERE sales_level_2 = h.sales_level_2 AND sales_level_3 = h.sales_level_3 AND sales_level_2 = CURRENT_USER));

I've tried creating a similar kind of SQL query but it was not helpful.
